# pyqt4 how to know textEdit field is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I want to know if textbox is empty or not. So, I made this code. But, if self.row is ' '  <- this is not working. Although, textEdit field is empty but, it's not recognize.

```
   def setUi(self):
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(MainWindow) 
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(155, 90, 471, 31))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))



   def bringcolumn(self):
    self.row = self.textEdit.toPlainText() 

    if self.row is '': #I want to know if self.row is empty of not.
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Message", "ERROR")
```

Comment: execute `print(type(self.row))`

Comment: Change `if self.row is ''` to `if str(self.row) == ""'`

Comment: type is str. As you comment, I changed. It's working!!! Thank you. @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if self.row is ''` to `if str(self.row) == ""`  ​​